# Is there any way to change combo box arrow button color in javafx?

Tags: javafx

[image]

I want to be able to change the combo box arrow button color not background color but the color of the button only to the color of the border and text fill both of which are set to #f0f0f0.

Is It possible, if so then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using css selectors you can change the arrow, and arrow button color however you want

```
.combo-box .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

.combo-box .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-size: 5;
}
```

to do this in code without editing the .css file, assuming your ComboBox is named `comboBox`

```
comboBox.lookup(".arrow").setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
comboBox.lookup(".arrow-button").setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you please tell me if there is a way to do this with code?

Comment: edited answer to include code snippet to accomplish same result without .css

Comment: Thank you very much!